# SQL INSERT from two tables

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, insert

I have 3 tables:

```
Employee(Employee_ID, First_Name, Last_Name)
Project(Project_ID, Project_Name)     
Task(Employee_ID, Project_ID, Assigned_Project_Task)
```

I want to insert `Employee_ID` from `Employee` to `Task` when I give the first and last name to the respective id (ex. `Employee_ID=1 First_Name=ABC Last_Name=XYZ` and I give ABC as first name and XYZ as last name, 1 will be put in `Employee_ID` field in the `Task` table), the same thing with `Project_ID` from `Project` table to `Task` table and lastly I need to give a name to it in the `Assigned_Project_Task` field in `Task` table.

> EX. Employee_ID=1, First_Name=ABC, Last_Name=XYZ in Employee

```
Project_ID=10, Project_Name=SomeProject in Project
```

If I give the following answers(in windows form in C#) `first_name=ABC`, `last_name=XYZ` and `project_name=SomeProject` and name the `task=NewTask`. (I give the task name from a txtbox in windows form)

It will put the in the `Task` table the following:

```
Employee_ID=1, Project_ID=10, Assigned_Project_Name=NewTask
```

How do I do this insert?

Comment: what server do you use in your project? MySQL or MSSQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You insert statement should look like this

```
INSERT INTO Task (Employee_ID, Project_Id, Assigned_Project_Name)
SELECT e.Employee_Id , p.Project_Id, 'NewTask'
FROM Employees e INNER JOIN Projects p 
WHERE e.last_name='XYZ' AND e.first_name='ABC' 
AND p.Project_Name='SomeProject';
```

You need find out how to build this query in C# yourself.